# Function not working as intended when changing fragment / activity

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

The app is for Attendance with barcode.

The scan function work fine until i change to other fragment / activity and back to it. If that happen then the camera will scan but it will not return anything and on back press it wont show any toast (even thought it should).
If i close the app then reopen it, open this fragment and scan, it back to normal again until i change to other fragment / activity.

There isnt any error message. So i dont know where the error is.

This is parts of my code that i believe have something to do with this bug:

onCreateView:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendance, container, false);


    fetch();

    return v;
}
```

fetch:

```
private void fetch() {

FirebaseRecyclerOptions <ModelEvent> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ModelEvent>()
.setQuery(query, snapshot -> new ModelEvent(
    Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("eventID").getValue()).toString(),
    Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("eventStatus").getValue()).toString()))
.build();

adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ModelEvent, ViewHolderEvent>(options) {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolderEvent onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_attendance, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolderEvent(view);
    }

    //Set data on each list
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderEvent viewHolderEvent, int i, @NonNull ModelEvent modelEvent) {
            viewHolderEvent.setStringStatus(modelEvent.getEventStatus());

            viewHolderEvent.buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    stringEventID = modelEvent.getEventID();

                    ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
                    options.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(ScanOptions.ALL_CODE_TYPES); 
                    options.setPrompt("Scan something");
                    options.setOrientationLocked(true);
                    options.setBeepEnabled(true);
                    fragmentLauncher.launch(options);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerViewAttendance.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

for scanner:

```
private final ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> fragmentLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(),
    result -> {
        //On Backpress
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            //Get data from QRCode
            stringQR = result.getContents();
            
            getUserData();
            setUserAttendance();


            //Notification
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Name: " + stringName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
    });
```

onStart:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

This is the full code: https://pastebin.com/e7XZN08i

Comment: what does adapter.startListening(); do

Comment: if it is some firebase listener then move it to onResume() so it can start listening again when coming back from another activity.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: the code work perfectly until i open another fragment / activity and then open this activity again, if that happen the scanner does work as intended as i explain before @AlexMamo

Comment: im sorry bu dont know what exactly adapter.startListening does.
how i put firebase listernet to onResume?
this is the first time i use FirebaseRecycler so i dont know what to move.
i move fetch() to onResume and it gave me error. @EndUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i just do many thing and ended up find what i should do.

```
 switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.nav_event:
        fragmentEvent = new FragmentEvent(); //i just need to add this on all case for some reason, the tutorial i use dont do this
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentEvent).commit();
        return true;
```

I also ask this on github:https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/695